# Javascript: Modify all occurrences of an email address

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, email, replace

Here's a challenging question that I couldn't figure out myself. 
This probably requires jquery and regex.

Figure out a script to **modify all occurrences of an email address** on a page as follows:

**Original email:**

```
cookies@yummybakery.com
```

Replace the 2nd char with "..." AND the char before the **last** punctuation mark + everything to the right of it with "...":

```
c...okies@yummybaker...
```

The target emails are each in an element of the class:

```
<p class="info">
```

And last, the easiest part, the replacement must only occur on a certain URL, e.g.:

```
if(window.location.pathname == '/users')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Please post any attempts at solving this problem yourself in your post.

Comment: What is the idea behind this question? The email addresses are rendered in the HTML before your JavaScript executes so they will be visible anyway.

Comment: You need to do it the other way around. Scrapers get the HTML and don't run any Javascript

Comment: If the whole point of this is to hide the emails from the spiders, it's going to fail miserably. You need to make the change on the server-side before it makes it to the client.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, someone mentioned that before to me as well, that JS and CSS is just client-side, so crawlers parsing the HTML will get away with the emails anyway. But I'm trying to implement this nonetheless, just to improve my JS skills, as I just can't figure out a logic for this by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use of string methods

```
x = 'cookies@yummybaker.com'
x = x.charAt(0) + '...' + x.substring(2, x.lastIndexOf('.')) + '...';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eYtY6/

```
/[a-z]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{3,4}/i.test(x) // regex to test emails
```

I'm not going to do all the work for you, but here is the gist of it. :P

http://jsfiddle.net/eYtY6/1 <-- fiddle with regex test

Comment: Thanks, this would only replace a single value though, and that's the part where I got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

OK, ignoring any issues with why this might be a bad idea, and assuming the email addresses occur directly within the `<p class="info">` elements you mentioned, you could try something like this:

```
if(window.location.pathname == '/users') {

  $("p.info").html(function(i,oldVal) {
    return oldVal.replace(/cookies@yummybakery\.com/g,"c...okies@yummybaker...");
  });

}
```

This makes use of the [`.html()` method](http://api.jquery.com/html/)'s ability to take a callback that processes the old html and returns the new.

If the "cookies@yummybakery.com" address was just an example and you want to do *all* possible email addresses then just to identify valid emails in the page you're going to need a [pretty complicated regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html), or one of many simplified versions.

Once you've decided on an appropriate regex you could do something like this:

```
var re = /emailMatchingRegexOfYourChoiceHere/g;

return oldVal.replace(re,function(match) {
   match.charAt(0) + '...' + match.substring(2, match.lastIndexOf('.')) + '...';
});
```

Comment: Wow, this is a perfect answer, great logic and considered all mentioned points, thanks!!!! I'm quite new to JS and I've been browsing for hours on a way to implement this. I found too many different methods and just couldn't figure out how to put together the right blocks to get a working function. 

I tried your first script as a test, it works great. I then integrated your second script (chose a regex & it's working!), but the matches are returned as blanks. I'm guessing the match function isn't working as it should... But I'll try to figure it out. 

Thanks for the help!